# Delphi and Indy10 problem with reading binary data

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy10

I have a problem with reading binary data from a network device. I am sending a 4 byte binary command to the device (a Lantronix XPort) and expect a 124 byte response from that device. When monitoring the communications with WireShark, I see the command being sent and the response from the device being returned. Yet, I keep getting an EidReadTimeout exception with message "Read Timed out"

This is the code:

```
function TXPort.ReadSetup(IP: string; var Setup: TXportSetup0): boolean;
var
  Cmd, Resp: TidBytes;
begin
  Result := False;
  TCP.Host := IP;
  SetLength(Cmd,4);
  Cmd[3] := XPortGetConfig;
  try
    TCP.Connect;
    TCP.IOHandler.WriteDirect(Cmd);
    TCP.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Resp,SizeOf(TXportSetup0),False);
    Move(Resp,Setup,SizeOf(TXportSetup0));
  except
    Exit
  end;
  TCP.Disconnect;
  if Setup.Cmd[3] = (XPortGetConfig + 1) then { if proper response received... }
    Result := True; { tell us }
end;
```

I know that the TCP.Disconnect should be in a 'finally'  section but this makes no difference at all.
I've searched numerous sites and fora and one even literally had the same code as I have, but working!
I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

Best,
Meindert

Comment: Did you check that `SizeOf(TXportSetup0)` was equal to 124?

Comment: Dang! The setuprecord I was trying to read, is 124 bytes in total. One field of it was defined as an array of four characters. In Delphi7 these were 8 bits, in Delphi XE they're 16 bits. So I was trying to read 128 bytes... Changing these to AnsiChar fixed it. Reading is now successful!
Thanks!!!

Comment: @M.Sprang unless the data is textual in nature, `Byte` would make more sense than `AnsiChar`.  Also, on a side note, you should be using `TCP.IOHandler.Write(Cmd)` instead of `TCP.IOHandler.WriteDirect(Cmd)`. And using `BytesToRaw(Resp,Setup,SizeOf(TXportSetup0))` instead of `Move(Resp,Setup,SizeOf(TXportSetup0))`, or you could use `TIdMemoryBufferStream` with `TCP.IOHandler.ReadStream()` to read directly into `Setup` without using an intermediate `TIdBytes` at all.

Comment: @Remy: I found that using Move(Resp[0],.... is the correct way, but I'll see if there's any benefit in using BytesToRaw. Using TidMemoryStream goes against all of my embedded DNA! I find it already disturbing that I need to use Move() or BytesToRaw() to get the data into and out of a TidBytes object. Knowing that the low level TCP functions all work with a simple buffer pointer and a byte count, adding all kinds of layers requiring unnecessary copying seems absurd to me. I appreciate how Indy takes away a lot of work, but I wish they had left a "raw to the bones" layer available.

Comment: @M.Sprang yes, you need to index into a dynamic array to access its actual bytes. `BytesToRaw()` handles that for you, as well as bounds checking to make sure the `TIdBytes` is large enough to copy the requested byte range. As for why reading into an intermediate `TIdBytes` is needed at all, it is because Indy 10 supports .NET, where raw memory access is not allowed (.NET support will be dropped in Indy 11). Using `TIdMemoryBufferStream` is a kind of "raw to the bones" solution to get around that limitation on non-DotNet systems by letting you use your own buffer pointer.

Comment: @M.Sprang technically, you can access the real "raw to the bones" socket layer in Indy, if you bypass the `IOHandler`'s higher-level reading/writing methods and go right to its underlying `Binding` reading/writing methods, which are just thin wrappers for the OS's socket API.